# Laravel eloquent ORM get sum of relational model column and order by

Tags: laravel

I am using Larave 4.2 with MySQL back-end.

I have two tables which have many relationship as below:

```
users  : id(PK), name
videos : id(PK), user_id(FK), title, file_size
```

I want to **get sum of size of videos for each user** hence I've created relationship as below:

```php
class User extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function videosSize() {
      return $this->hasOne('Video')
        ->selectRaw('user_id, sum(file_size) as videosSize')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
    }

    public function getVideosSizeAttribute() {
      // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
      if ( ! array_key_exists('videosSize', $this->relations)) 
        $this->load('videosSize');

      $related = $this->getRelation('videosSize')->first();

      // then return the count directly
      return ($related) ? (int) $related->videosSize : 0;
    }
}
```

And I am using it like:

```php
$user = User::with('videosSize')->get();
```

And it returns array like:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => abc
            [videos_size] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 18
                    [videosSize] => 8731801
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [name] => abc
            [videos_size] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 19
                    [videosSize] => 7931881
                )
        )
    .. so on
)
```

But however, I would like to get it like:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => abc
            [videos_size] => 8731801

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [name] => abc
            [videos_size] => 7931881
        )
    .. so on
)
```

And later on I want to **sort** it **by videos_size**.

I **don't** want to **use join** statement with raw query as I've many more `with` statements there with `User` model and I cannot change them because there are a lot of things depending on the nested array it returns.

How can I do it?

Comment: I am a bit unsure about videos_size and videosSize being used? where did you define the videos_size (written separately) in your model ?so that  your dd dumps that?

Comment: @patricio I am sorry for the late reply, but you can study this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators explains why the videos_sizes is there even if it is not defined any where :)

Comment: Something seems strange here, unless my brain isn't working. Why is [video_size] populated with an `array`, and not an `int` - you are using the eloquent accessor... I feel like your videoSizes method is conflicting with the call? It almost looks like your output is filling it in with the return value of `videoSizes` not `getVideoSizesAttribute`

Comment: Might be, I am not sure as I am facing this kind of situation first time. So can you help me? Let me know what should I change and get the desired result? If I directly get an int for videoSizes then life will be easy to order by it using eloquent.